# Weird behavior with Canvas Screenspace with Camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I am building an application for Android-Oculus Quest. I set the canvas to Screenspace-Camera and it works perfectly fine in Player on Windows. That is, the texts are visible in the game view through Oculus Rift. But when I build it for Quest, the UI Texts disappear. They are nowhere to be seen. It is not just texts, even simple images are not to be seen. This is my set up. What is the mistake I am committing?

[image: Canvas]

[image: Text_UI]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. I guess your text is just too small. Try to scale your text and see what's happening